# Добавить ещё одну строку в INNER JOIN mysql

Tags: inner-join, mysql

```
FROM notifications INNER JOIN users ON users.vk_id = notifications.from
```

Как добавить в INNER JOIN такое:

```
или notifications.from = 0
```

То есть как-то так:

```
ON users.vk_id = notifications.from || ON notifications.from = 0
```

Но не знаю синтаксиса. Помогите :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
FROM notifications INNER JOIN users ON (users.vk_id = notifications.from OR notifications.from = 0)
```